# Turning off bezier curve smoothing of freehand feature editing in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing

In ArcGIS 10.2, I am trying to create a very specific feature using the freehand tool under "Create Features". Once you complete a section of the feature it is automatically simplified using bezier curves. At the scale I am attempting to work, this simplification is a major issue.

Does anyone have any knowledge of how to turn off this auto-simplification? It seems to be built into the tool as far as I can tell from ArcGIS Help and other mentions of the tool online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "stream vertices," which does not simplify on completion.

Full instructions [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m70000003z000000). In short, after you've placed the first vertex, right-click and enable streaming. Vertices will be placed at intervals according to the streaming tolerance set in Editor options.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately you cannot switch the  auto-simplification off.**

> "The freehand drawing line is automatically smoothed into Bézier
>   curves."

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m700000067000000

Workround you can convert your feature to a **cartographic representation** and you will be able to use the freehand tools without the automated part.

> On the Representation toolbar, convert this feature to a free
>   representation by clicking Representation > Free Representation >
>   Convert to Free Representation.

[image]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Exercise_4_Working_with_free_representations/00s50000005m000000/